# Override Helpers default timeout

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

My scala test fails with

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20 seconds]
exception
```

I've found where the timeout is defined(`play.api.test.Helpers`), but I don't understand how to override it from my test.

```
 trait DefaultAwaitTimeout {

      /**
       * The default await timeout.  Override this to change it.
       */
      implicit def defaultAwaitTimeout: Timeout = 20.seconds
```

Could you, please, help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override it in your test suite object/class which uses this trait ( it is declared as `with DefaultAwaitTimeout` or `extends DefaultAwaitTimeout`). Then somewhere in the body of this object/class you can just override it:

```
override def defaultAwaitTimeout: Timeout = 42.seconds
```

Comment: Why doesn't setting `akka.http.server.request-timeout = 130s` or `play.server.akka.requestTiemout = infinite` in application.conf works?